# What is the best way to use drag and drop in Angular 4 that will work on tablets

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drag-and-drop

I am developing an Angular 4 application where I'm using [ngx-chips](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips) to input tags. Then I have a button where the user can create a category. The tag can be added into category. The way I wish to add the tag into categories is via drag and drop. Also I wish that the tag inside category can be dragged and dropped into another category or the tag inside category can be dropped back into input tags.

I can not find any library which would allows me to drag tags and drop tag into category which will works on tables, on any browser. The ngx_chips has drag and drop but it does not work on tables.

I also look at in other libraries like [ng2-dnd](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd) , [ng-drag-drop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-drag-drop) or [ng2-dragula](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dragula)  but I have similar issue with it. It works on any browser on PCs and it works on chrome browser on tablets, but it does not work on other browser on tablets like firefox safari.

I also look at hammerJS and I found nice presentation on [swiping](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-hammerjs-touch-gesture-in-angular-2) but nothing on drag and drop. One source which I found on hammerJS [here](https://gist.github.com/jordangarcia/30d73b5bf8c4811e9893) which uses Jquery, which I wish to avoid as I do not want to mix Angular with Jquery.

So the question is: What is the best way to use drag and drop in Angular that will work on any tablets, phone and on any browser? Or if anyone has any other suggestions please let me know. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried using Draggable of GreenSock? It's very friendly with AngularJs. I didn't used in Angular2( or above ) but I think that still work.